# Parasyte: the Maxim OST episode 13

Tags: music, parasyte

What is the song played in the beginning of episode 13 of Parasyte: the Maxim at 00:00:29? Please be specific. It's quite close to "Next to You", and has a tune that was played when Kana first saw Shinichi in and got freaked out, in pure piano (synthesizer), but with a different tempo/speed/etc. And I'm sure it's not "Next to You".

Comment: It's definitely a remixed version of "Next to You." [This comes close](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NumVrbn5CRg), but is still a bit different. It's probably an unreleased track.

Comment: Have you tried [*this* anime version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvCPNy3USaU) of the tune yet? It's the softest tune I could find...

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the tune you are looking for is [Next to You-Anime Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvCPNy3USaU). This one is different from the [Original One](https://youtu.be/DVl9XNs8jqw) in the aspects of being slower and softer, and with a totally different instrument playing it and from the other [Anime Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RRQjhlSUIg) in the same terms.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find it in any of the OSTs. It might be an unreleased track for an unreleased OST like Krazer said, but that's anyone's guess.